# parsing stdout in bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to write a script to start a uart client.
if the uart client opens - do a, if failes - do b
I'm using file descriptor to read the output of the client,
but it always fails and I'm thinking maybe the client writes to the fd instead of the /dev/ttyS*.

UPDATE: I'm sure that uart_client is writing to the fd because there are no interrupts to the tty driver.

am I doing something wrong? is there another way?

here is my script:

```
exec 3< ./uart_client

while read line; do
   case "$line" in
   *background*)
      echo "'$line' Done. creating connection"
      DO A...
      break
      ;;
   *Cannot*)
      echo "'$line' no uart. Exiting loop"
      DO B...
      break
      ;;
   *)
      echo "'$line'."
      ;;
   esac
done <&3
exec 3<&-

echo done ...
```

Comment: What is _not_ working here?

Comment: I'm always going into the Cannot case. while running ./uart_client always works...

Comment: Are you sure, the uart client writes to fd instead of  serial port `/dev/ttyS2`? What output does `./uart_client` produce?

Comment: is there a way to check it? and how?

Comment: Change the read operation from `<&3` and remove `exec 3<` when running `uart_client` and read from `done < /dev/ttyS0` or `ttyS1`

Comment: using cat /proc/interrupts I can see that there were no writes to the serial port (the uart_client sends some commands to init)